# Counts of words vs occurrences in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I find the number of occurrences vs their counts in a string using snowflake?

Eg: Hello Hello Hello how are you.

The expected output should be

```
word count(*) 
Hello 3 
How 1 
are 1 
you 1 
.   1
```

Comment: Please show some effort in solving this task on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function such s `split_to_table()`:

```
select value
from table(split_to_table('Hello Hello Hello how are you.', ' ') as s
group by value;
```

Note:  This does not split `.` separately.

Comment: Thanks Gordan, I have tried this but doesn't seem to work for me.                                             select seq,index,value,columnname,* from tablename, lateral split_to_table(tablename.columnname, ''). Can you please advise what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

select companyname,c.value::string as split_ans
from tablename,
lateral flatten(input=>split(Columnname, ' ')) c;

```
 select count(*),split_ans from tempcompany1 group by split_ans order by 1 desc
```

This one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this. Mind that this relies on a delimiter and therefore will only split to columns based on spaces. If you really want to count the `.` you could added a union (commented out for now)

```
create or replace temporary table test as
select 'hello hello hello how are you.' as txt

select value as txt, count(*) as cnt
from test, lateral split_to_table(test.txt, ' ')
group by value
--union all
--select '.', length(txt)-length(replace(txt,'.',''))
--from test;
```